# What is the default password for a Samsung ml-2851nd?

Tags: passwords

The web interface says, SyncThru Web Service. The top of the page says  "M262x 282x Series." The printer is a "Samsung ml-2851nd".

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](http://wiki.sirkit.ca/2011/05/samsung-syncthru-web-service-default-username-and-password/)

```
Username/ID:  admin
Password: sec00000 (that's 5 zeros)
```